# How different it is to manually test a web application which is developed using MEAN stack?

Tags: manual-testing, web-application, angular, nodejs

Are there any specific details to be taken care of, when manually testing a  Web Application developed using Angular JS,Node.js?

As these two frameworks are javascript based,what are the features to consider in browsers like cookies?

Will there be any difference in testing web applications(manually through browsers)  which are developed using different technologies?

Answer (score 1):

Manually testing the application developed using two different technologies don't have any key differences.

In manual testing, you are going to concentrate on the functionality flow, UI based on user stories.